# WordPress the_date skipping at intervals inside a loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have made a custom loop in WordPress and for some reason, the date is being skipped on random intervals, even though the other post content is getting pulled in successfully every time.

Any ideas, because it is completely baffling me!

For example, a list of posts and when the date is missing:

1. Date
2. Date
3. No date
4. Date
5. Date
6. No date
7. Date
8. No date
9. No date
10. No date

Here is the code, including all the loops:

```
    <?php query_posts('category_name=News&posts_per_page=10'); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

    <article>
        <div>
            <p>PUBLISHED: <?php the_date(); ?></p>
            <h4><a class="news_title_link" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <br />
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Read more</a>
        </div>  
        <div>
        <?php if ( function_exists( 'get_the_image' ) ) { get_the_image(array('default_size' => 'thumbnail','default_image' => '/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/default-thumb.jpg'));} ?>
        </div>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: By random, do you mean with every refresh the post dates appear at totally different intervals from the previous page load?

Comment: No, they are in the order I specified in the list. I should change the question as it is misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One likely cause could be that the consecutive posts with no dates are all published on the same day as the one with a date that they all immediately follow.

In your example, the second and third posts may have the same publish date, which is causing the third post to not display a date. Likewise, posts 7 to 10 may share the same publish date, which is causing the last three posts to not display dates.

That, as far as I've experienced, is how `the_date()` works. It prints a unique date only once throughout a loop.

I work around it by either:

- Using `the_time()` instead of `the_date()` and specifying a full date format, or
- Calling `unset($previousday)` just after my `the_post()` call

Comment: You sir, are awesome, it sounds like you have hit the nail on the head. I will give it a try now. Thanks!

Comment: I added the unset previous day to the loop and it worked a treat. Thank you for uncovering that mystery!

Comment: You sir, are a gentleman and a scholar. This was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Both Wordpress' [the_date() document](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_date) and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47190/date-not-appearing-in-custom-query suggest this.

```
<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2017, there is another simpler solution. You can simply use:

```
echo get_the_date();
```

instead of `the_date();`. For me, it was the exact same problem with dates only displaying if they are different from the date before.